# BACKBONE collection.create -- Change POST parameters

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backend in JAVA. For new items, we use the following URL:

api/new/house  (It is POST)

API Expects in the Request Body this: "newhouseid"

I cant send "key": "value". Server wants only quotes. If I do the following:

```
    model = new HouseModel({


        });

        model.save({key: "12345"});
```

This is how it arrives on Body on the REST API:
{"id":"12345"}

In the payload body, I need it to be like:
"12345"

Comment: don't really understand why you need a collection ?

Comment: I need to POST to server just an ID. I use native AJAX, but requirement is to use backbone built in AJAX..  So no key: value in parameters.... just a string.

Comment: I meant why a `collection` & not a `model` ?

Comment: If it can be done with model then great :)